# Call disappear view event

Tags: ios, swift

I have a `ContainerView` and `ViewController` inside. Then when user click on button, i hide this `ContainerView` (`myContainerView.hidden = true`), but `ViewController` continue working and it is cause freezes. How can i hide `ContainerView` and **stop** `ViewController` inside, to trigger `viewWillDisappear` method. I don't need kill it every time.

The same behavior have `UITabBarController` when you change tab, it just stops controller.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> Calling the standard function **removeFromParentViewController** we remove
>   the current Detail Controller from the Container hierarchy. When this
>   function is called, the function **didMoveToParentViewController** is
>   automatically called with nil as parameter on the Detail Controller.

For Adding again

```
- (void)presentDetailController:(UIViewController*)detailVC{

    //0. Remove the current Detail View Controller showed 
    if(self.currentDetailViewController){
        [self removeCurrentDetailViewController];
    }

    //1. Add the detail controller as child of the container
    [self addChildViewController:detailVC];

    //2. Define the detail controller's view size
    detailVC.view.frame = [self frameForDetailController];

    //3. Add the Detail controller's view to the Container's detail view and save a reference to the detail View Controller
    [self.detailView addSubview:detailVC.view];
    self.currentDetailViewController = detailVC;

    //4. Complete the add flow calling the function didMoveToParentViewController
    [detailVC didMoveToParentViewController:self];

}
```

Comment: ```let scannerVC = ScannerViewController()

        self.addChildViewController(scannerVC)

        scannerVC.view.frame = self.searchContainer.frame
        self.searchContainer.addSubview(scannerVC.view)
        scannerVC.didMoveToParentViewController(self)```
i did this but it's not working...

Comment: because in viewDidLoad i have: self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()